# Can we User Google VPS virtual machine to Publish App on play store

Tags: android

hello friend I am looking for an Answer for "Can we User Google VPS virtual machine to Publish App on play store."

Google also track physical address of pc if there is any suspended account in this area Chances are you might also get suspended with out any reason, my question is the Virtual machine is thousand miles away from you in a data center their are thousand of machine their might be any one else who is upload app from there , my Question is it Save to use for Accessing Google play dev Console?

Comment: You can make use of CD/CD pipeline from any of Git repository like Github, Gitlab, Bitbucket or Bitrise CI/CD tool and make it automated to publish your app through it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Windows VM on AWS and upload the APK through it.

Comment: does the Physical address make trouble for me in future there will be a lot of people using it in same data center a lot of people will have same physical address .